# webkit-background-clip: text working on mozilla but not on chrome?

Tags: html, css, text, webkit, background-image

I have made 3 div with text and a background image, using webkit-background-clip to show the image behind.

With my code it works fine on firefox but where I have altered the size of the text (using transform/scale in css) for design purposes these transformed section of heading are not working in chrome but they are on firefox. I have used span class tags to change the size of the font, these are the sections that are not showing in chrome but are in firefox?

examples below:

[image: Example of website in forefox]

Below example of google chrome

[image: how the sanme site looks on chrome]

The parts that appear to be missing all have span class tags on with transforms

```css
    .column-boxes {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 100%;
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 36px;
    }

    .column-box {
        height: auto;
        min-height: 300px;
        min-width: 300px;
        max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
        width: 30%;
        margin: 0 auto 2% auto;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .welcome-text {
        color: #888;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 4vw;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding-bottom: 36px;
        margin-left: 2.8%;
        /*text-shadow:
                    -1px -1px 0 #f3f3f3,
                    1px -1px 0 #f3f3f3,
                    -1px 1px 0 #f3f3f3,
                    1px 1px 0 #f3f3f3;*/
    }

    /* span for welcome text */

    .welcome-text-clash {
        color: #ccc;
        font-weight: 900;
        letter-spacing: -0.07em;

    }

    /*.box-title {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 108px;
        color: #fff;
        line-height: 92px;
        text-shadow:
                    -1px -1px 0 #999,
                    1px -1px 0 #999,
                    -1px 1px 0 #999,
                    1px 1px 0 #999;

    }*/

    .box-title-1 {
        font-size: 3.2vw;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-image: url("http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/themes/current-build/images/fashion-photography-strip-and-stare.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 2.5vw;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .box-title-2 {
        font-size: 8vw;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-image: url("http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/themes/current-build/images/kensey-foods-photography-nectarine-tart.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 6vw;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .box-title-3 {
        font-size: 4.5vw;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        letter-spacing: -0.05em;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-image: url("http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/themes/current-build/images/imogen-thomas-glass-sculpture.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 3.4vw;
        text-align: center;


    }

    .box-title-1-a {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 7.7vw;
        line-height: 6vw;

    }
    .box-title-1-b {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 9.6vw;
        line-height: 11.3vw;
        transform: scale(1, 1.6);
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1.6); /* Firefox */
    }
    .box-title-1-c {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 7.5vw;
        line-height: 6.7vw;
        transform: scale(1, 1.2);
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1.2); /* Firefox */

    }

    .box-title-2-a {
        font-size: 8.1vw;
        line-height: 6.5vw;
    }
    .box-title-2-b {
        font-size: 7.8vw;
        line-height: 6.1vw;
    }
    .box-title-2-c {
        font-size: 10.7vw;
        line-height: 8.2vw;
        margin-left: -1%;
    }

    .box-title-3-a {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 10.2vw;
        line-height: 10.2vw;
        transform: scale(1, 1.3);
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1.3); /* Firefox */

    }
    .box-title-3-b {
        font-size: 7.5vw;
        line-height: 5.1vw;
    }
    .box-title-3-c {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 7.5vw;
        line-height: 8vw;
        transform: scale(1, 1.34);
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1.34); /* Firefox */

    }

    #commercial-box {
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-image: url("http://testsiteclash.co.uk/wp-content/themes/current-build/images/fashion-photography-strip-and-stare.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<section class="column-boxes">
        <h1 class="welcome-text"><span class="welcome-text-clash">Clash</span> 
    <span style="letter-spacing: -0.09em">&</span><span class="welcome-text- 
    clash">Clash</span>PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
        <div id="commercial-box" class="column-box">
            <h2 class="box-title-1">COMMERCIAL<span class="box-title-1- 
    a">PHOT</span><br><span class="box-title-1-b">OGR</span><br><span 
    class="box-title-1-c">APHY</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="food-box" class="column-box">
            <h2 class="box-title-2">FOOD<span class="box-title-2-a">PHOT</span> 
    <br><span class="box-title-2-b">OGRA</span><br><span class="box-title-2- 
    c">PHY</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div id="product-box" class="column-box">
            <h2 class="box-title-3">PRODUCT<span class="box-title-3- 
    a">PHO</span><br><span class="box-title-3-b">TOGR</span><br><span 
    class="box-title-3-c">APHY</span></h2>
        </div>    
    </section>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have searched for 2 days now looking for an answer and have tried all sorts of compatibility, display varaints etc... and am at a loss

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change your display to inline on those spans instead of inline block and see if it woks on both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Jason i replaced with inline on everything apart from the first line with text on it and it now shows the picture behind but it has not performed the transform: scale( 1, 1.6) etc... on the certain letters that have the span and transform class on them? it has also got rid of the scale transforms in forefox too? In firefox if i change the certain span back to inline block it performs the transform?

Comment: Yeah I realized that when you wrote the previous comment. Your scale when its on inline-block actually works. What doesn't seem to work is transparent fill of text. If you set -webkit-text-fill-color: black. Youll see the scale works.

Comment: Thanks @jason i have had a look and even by using rgba values and a low opacity it still doesnt reveal the image behind? is there anything else i can do? as i am at a loss? I do have a jquery function opening a div on clicking the box with text in, do you think this may have something to do with it?

Comment: Na it's got nothing to do with jquery. Even without it, is not working for me on Chrome.

Comment: thanks @Jason ive looked at other prefixes for text fill but none seem to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190162/discussion-between-jason-and-paul-stephen-davis).